# When to consider a Linux kernel overloaded

Tags: linux, bash, memory, swap

I am currently working on a Linux system and yesterday I've noticed that The system was slow answering my http requests. I've opened top and I've found this kind situation, in which the Memory seemed to be busy at 95~99%. 
Since the cpu load seems to be low and the swap file quite free, I am wondering when I should consider a linux system overloaded and when not. I know that linux has a different memory handle system, right? Maybe this memory load is not related with the bad reaching of the https server (I mean, it could be related to the network layer or whatever...anyway not related to the memory)?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: >60% I/O wait time. That's your issue.

Comment: Is that Java program involved in processing http requests?

Comment: @Mat is "wa." the parameter that you are considering? Could you exlpain me what does it mean?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, yes, it's Adobe AEM

Answer (score 1):

The term of Linux kernel overloaded is little bit not aligned with reality. You can overload something. For example HDD is overloaded, CPU is overloaded, RAM is full and you are swapping.

you should check all the cases not just CPU load and mem usage... What about io top (maybe your HDD is overloaded?), jnettop (network?).

In your case i suspect you simply use too much RAM and start Swapping 820MB in swap already. Swapping means using swap partition (usually HDD but depends on your configuration) as kind of extension of RAM (similar to windows pagefile). But since HDDs are insanely slower compared to RAM the system takes big performance hit in this case.

Another suspicious thing is CPU usage of 23%.... How many cores (incl.hyperthreading) your system has? Is it possible that your application is not using threads? Therefore your CPU usage is only ~25% but it actually means single core is running 100% (overloaded) and 3 other cores are idle(nothing to do)? Therefore you are having single process/thread application which is saturating one core.

Comment: My system should have 2 cores. Te main running application is Adobe AEM and as far as I know it takes advantage of both cores. I've used HTOP to have a better panoramic of the processes and, despite the load not get ~25% the system keeps taking long pauses answering to the http interface

Comment: In that case I would check for io load... And why is it so... Directly caused by application or indirectly by swapping

Comment: At the end I've discovered that someone setted 1600 workflows speaded on 15 parallels processes...so that..here we are...